# HTML tag doesn't closed properly in loop

Tags: php, html

After long hours of debug I found the cause of my problem, my code look like this

```
<a><div>

<?php <p> echo $item_content </p> ?>

</div></a>
```

but it produced strange DOM.

My debugging fount the $item_content contains un-closed tag that's why my dom messed up. I used `htmlspecialchars($item_content)` and it work fine. But I still want to display the HTML, how should I proceed?

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error for that. Your PHP script shouldn't even run. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @Barmar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687141/wired-html-dom-produced-by-php

Comment: I don't understand. What does that question have to do with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows

```
<a>
    <div>
        <p><?php echo $item_content;?></p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Strange. Which output you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it like

```
<a>
    <div>
        <?php echo "<p>".$item_content."</p>"; ?>
    </div>
</a>
```

Or you can do like

```
<a>
    <div>
        <p><?php echo $item_content;?></p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just try this:

```
 <a><div>
 <?php 
  echo "<p>".$item_content."</p>";
 ?>
 </div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided won't give the effect you describe (since the paragraph tags will throw errors as they are HTML and not PHP). Assuming that is just an error in your test case (when you make reduced test case, please ensure it actually reflects the problem you are having!) and going by your description of the problem:

If you have invalid HTML in the variable, then you need to fix it before you echo it into your DOM.

The best way to do this is to go to the source and fix it there. If you can't do that, then the you can try to do it at runtime by parsing the code into a DOM and then serialising it back to HTML.

```
<?php

$invalid = "<div>Testing";
$valid = "";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$success = $dom->loadHTML($invalid);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    $valid .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

echo $valid;
```